# Windows Driver - HCK Signature not Working 8/8.1/2012

Tags: windows, driver, filter-driver

I've developed a filter driver for windows 10 that I sign via Attestation and am able to use with no issues. Recently a deployment was needed on a 2012 server installation (The driver is backwards compatible and works 100% with test signing on / verification off). I was led to believe that an EV signature on the file was enough prior to Windows 10, but this did not work for me, and I've seen others online say the same. Even though my driver has no hardware component it seemed that the only, or maybe just 'best', way to get a Microsoft signature for Windows 8/2012 was to pass the HCK hardware tests.

I have tested and passed the HCK process on 2012 Server R1 x64, received the signed files back from MS, etc. But I am still met with an unsigned driver error when trying to install on a fresh installation. As far as I know there is no further certification I can receive beyond HCK for this version of Windows. Attestation obviously works for W10 but not something older, and just an EV isn't helping either. My driver returned post-HCK has both my Sha1 EV and a Sha256 from MS.

I can't find any documentation of what's going on here. My understanding is that this driver should be "ready to be shipped" and that I should have no issues deploying it. Is there a further step, a reason this would happen, any guidance someone can give, etc?

Comment: does the windows is fully updated? sound like a root CA issue.

Comment: Yes, that's the impression I got as well (since I had Microsoft issues on windows 7 VMs doing things like installing visual studio) but this occurs on a fully updated 2012 R1 - build 9200 machine. I reached out to Microsoft support, which apparently costs a pretty penny, and they were able to reproduce. I'm waiting to hear back.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Microsoft was actually that due to this being a filter driver and \ the fact that we were using legacy install methods (InstallHinfSection DefaultInstall rather than plug and play) we were actually hitting an old known bug in Windows where CAT files were not properly installed with the driver.

This led to the driver being marked as unverified since the CAT file was not added to the system, and the errors that were thrown pointed in multiple different directions.

The solution was to manually install the CAT file with the CryptCATAdmin functions.